# Trouble Building Trilinos (Scientific Computation Library) on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, fortran, scientific-computing, trilinos

I am trying to build the [Trilinos](http://trilinos.sandia.gov/) library on Mac OS X 10.6.8, basically following the instructions on [this page](https://code.google.com/p/trilinos/wiki/TrilinosHandsOnTutorial) and the [CMake Quickstart document](http://pastebin.com/LBuDhj8h) included with Trilinos.

In order to build it with CMake, the instructions recommend setting up a directory, e.g. /usr/local/trilinos, creating a ./do-configure script in it and running it. My script is:

```
EXTRA_ARGS=$@

cmake \
    -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=DEBUG \
    -D Trilinos_ENABLE_TESTS:BOOL=ON \
    $EXTRA_ARGS \
    ${TRILINOS_HOME}
```

Running this script starts the configuration, until an error appears. The verbose output can be found here: http://pastebin.com/abrEghD7

I think the relevant part of the message is:

```
-- Verifying Fortran/CXX Compiler Compatibility - Failed
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.7/share/cmake/Modules/FortranCInterface.cmake:284 (message):
  The Fortran compiler:

    /usr/local/bin/gfortran

  and the CXX compiler:

    /usr/bin/c++

  failed to compile a simple test project using both languages.  The output
  was:
```

However, I cannot explain why the script blames the Fortran and C++ compilers. I have tested the Fortran compiler with "Hello World", and used the C++ compiler of OS X for entire projects. As far as I can tell, both compilers work properly.

Can anyone guess what might be wrong?

EDIT: Seems like it is some compatibility issue, not a problem with the indivual compilers.

Answer (score 1):

When I compile paraview. I set my CXX compiler to `g++` and not the standard `c++` as cmake does. Because otherwise I see a similar error.

Comment: I tried `g++` by setting an option in the `do-configure` script. The error remains the same.

Comment: Did you check that it says `and the CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++`?

Comment: Yes. It says:

-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++ -- works



-- Verifying Fortran/CXX Compiler Compatibility - Failed
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.7/share/cmake/Modules/FortranCInterface.cmake:284 (message):
  The Fortran compiler:

    /usr/local/bin/gfortran

  and the CXX compiler:

    /usr/bin/g++

  failed to compile a simple test project using both languages.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get gfortran from? Builds from most sources don't support mac specific extensions like `-arch` which might make problems trying to combine both of them. Or they might just be different versions (if you're gfortran is much newer than your g++ they might be trying to pull in incompatible runtime versions).

In the numerical python community (which depends a lot on fortran) the recommended source for OS X is the binary from [here](http://r.research.att.com/tools/). This is matched to the XCode gcc version and supports the Mac specific extensions.